# Add data to JTable section code, casting issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm trying to input a row in already created Table, I found a solution in this website but it doesn't work for me. I extracted the 'JTable section code' and created a new class, it is the following one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] columnToken = {"No. consecutivo", "Token", "Lexema", "No. de linea"};
    String[] columnError = {"No. consecutivo", "Error", "No. de linea"};

    Object[][] datac1= {};
    Object[][] datac2= {};

    JTable tabTokens = new JTable(datac1, columnToken);
    JTable tabError = new JTable(datac2, columnError);

    JFrame frameTokens = new JFrame("JTable Tokens Display");
    JFrame frameError = new JFrame("JTable Errors Display");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JScrollPane tokenTabContainer = new JScrollPane(tabTokens);
    JScrollPane errorTabContainer = new JScrollPane(tabError);

    panel.add(tokenTabContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frameTokens.getContentPane().add(panel);

    panel.add(errorTabContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frameError.getContentPane().add(panel);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        DefaultTableModel token100 = (DefaultTableModel) tabTokens.getModel();
        token100.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});

        DefaultTableModel token101 = (DefaultTableModel) tabTokens.getModel();
        token101.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});

        DefaultTableModel token102 = (DefaultTableModel) tabTokens.getModel();
        token102.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});
    }

    frameTokens.pack();
    frameTokens.setVisible(true);
    //frameError.pack();
    //frameError.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

The error appeared is the next one:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

I know it's a casting problem, but this is the only solution I founded in internet.
I need to input data multiple times in a cycle, so I don't know another 'input design', could anyone help me please? 
Thank you!

Comment: why not just add the row directly to tabTokens isntead of creating an intermediary object that ends up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTable tabTokens = new JTable(datac1, columnToken);
```

When you create a table using two arrays like that the JTable uses an inner class as the TableModel, not the DefaultTableModel.

If you want to use the `DefaultTableModel` then the code should be like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, column);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Now when you access the `TableModel` of the `JTable` it will be a `DefaultTableModel` and you can use the `addRow(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a DefaultTableModel and set your table's model to it.
Then you can call addRow on the DefaultTableModel object you created.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] columnToken = {"No. consecutivo", "Token", "Lexema", "No. de linea"};
    String[] columnError = {"No. consecutivo", "Error", "No. de linea"};

    Object[][] datac1= {};
    Object[][] datac2= {};

    DefaultTableModel dtmTokens = new DefaultTableModel(datac1, columnToken);
    DefaultTableModel dtmError = new DefaultTableModel(datac2, columnError);

    JTable tabTokens = new JTable(dtmTokens);
    JTable tabError = new JTable(dtmError);


    JFrame frameTokens = new JFrame("JTable Tokens Display");
    JFrame frameError = new JFrame("JTable Errors Display");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JScrollPane tokenTabContainer = new JScrollPane(tabTokens);
    JScrollPane errorTabContainer = new JScrollPane(tabError);

    panel.add(tokenTabContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frameTokens.getContentPane().add(panel);

    panel.add(errorTabContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frameError.getContentPane().add(panel);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        dtmTokens.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});

        dtmTokens.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});

        dtmTokens.addRow(new Object[]{"Hola", 100, 196, "adios"});
    }

    frameTokens.pack();
    frameTokens.setVisible(true);
    //frameError.pack();
    //frameError.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it was helpful! :)